# How to add descriptions to keras model and load it from saved model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I train and save CNN keras model as it follows:

```
callback = EarlyStopping(monitor=monitor, mode='auto', patience=patience)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('Models/CNN.h5', monitor=monitor, verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[callback, mc]
)
```

Once training is completed, I would like to add a description to the saved model similar to "This model trained with 1000 dogs/cats images". Then, when I load the model, I would like to load this description somehow like that:

```
model = load_model(Models/CNN.h5)
print(model.description())
"This model trained with 1000 dogs/cats images"
```

Is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: Afaik, not that easily (never tried it so not sure). But you might want to look into https://www.tensorflow.org/responsible_ai/model_card_toolkit/guide

Comment: Looks like it generates an extra model card file that includes info of the model. If it is the case, then it is no different than creating a simple .txt file and putting the info there. I was planning a more compact solution without creating any extra files. But thanks for your time and comment (: